# Can i reuse license of Magento Enterprise?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have a source code of Magento Enterprise, it is belong to my friend, can i reuse the source code to update to my server? I want to ask if i upload source code Magento Enterprise to my server, any have reflect to license of my friend? or i can use this source but can't get support of Magento?

Comment: You are not allowed to use more than one instance under a single Enterprise Licence. I thought that officially this isn't allowed even for local development purposes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Enterprise Licenses and SE is not the place for this as you should contact Magento directly about licensing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Enterprise Licenses and SE is not the place for this as you should contact Magento directly about licensing.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. Magento EE license is based per server so if you upload it to another server you'll need to purchase an extra license.