# Getting a copy of Magento 2 Commerce for development/testing

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2-commerce

There are 3 versions of Magento 2

- Magento 2 Open Source
- Magento 2 Commerce
- Magento 2 Commerce Cloud

Open Source is publically available and downloadable to everyone. Commerce Cloud is hosted on their servers with restricted access (via git and pipelines).

Magento 2 Commerce should, from my understanding, have the same code as Cloud but be hosted on your own server. This means once you have signed up to a Commerce subscription you will be given a copy of the code for development/customization/testing.

I want to know if it is possible to get a copy of Commerce code without having an active subscription. I have searched several places and the closest I can see on Magento site is this request a demo page https://magento.com/schedule-a-demo though it is unclear if this is a business demo or technical demo.

I was able to find a demo Magento 2 Commerce store that a module developer had made publically available for people to test both front end and admin. However, it did not have some features enabled that I was interested in (B2B/company accounts) and I could not see the code/files.

If it is possible to get a copy of this code can you then install it on a server (local or via a service such as AWS)? What are the licensing restrictions on what you can do on such a server?

I have searched for information on this online but I have yet to find a concrete answer if this is possible or not. Ideally, I would like an official Magento 2 source that this is possible/not possible or a recommendation on which track I need to go down to get this (Magento University, contact Magento via phone).

Comment: you are asking for the Magento commerce version & that is also without subscription. How anyone can provide this to you it is not legal

Comment: It's likely that this is the case. If so is there an official source confirming that?

Comment: For now you can [refer this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83301/can-i-reuse-license-of-magento-enterprise/83302#83302) about the license scheme of Magento EE & for the further explation I am searching the resource & update you soon!

Comment: I have posted the information as an answer you can refer that & the provided document into it for the better understanding of the license terms of magento regarding the usage of magento commerce edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 Commerce edition is provided under the license terms defined by Magento & any one can have/allowed to access the Magento 2 commerce edition only by subscribing to their service &/or purchasing their service under the license agreement that they have maintained for the usage of their software.

Here is their terms for the software availability to any Individual/Company

> Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement (including
>   Customer’s compliance with the applicable Documentation) and payment
>   of the applicable Subscription Fees (as defined below), Magento grants
>   Customer a limited, personal, revocable, **non-exclusive**,
>   **non-transferrable**, **nonsublicensable license to install**, reproduce and
>   use internally the Software, as provided to Customer in source code
>   format, and create and use Modifications of the Software, in both
>   cases for the sole purpose of creating and running Customer’s Sites.

Here I have also found one clause into this license agreement for the restrictions:

> Customer shall not (and shall ensure that its employees, contractors
>   and other third parties do not):
>
> 1. Exploit the licenses set forth in Section 2A above for any purpose other than creating and maintaining the Sites used for promoting,
>      selling or providing the Customer’s products and services to End
>      Users;
> 2. **Provide, use, or allow others to use**, the Software for the benefit of third parties;
> 3. **Reverse engineer, disassemble, decompile** or apply any other process or procedure to derive the source code of any closed source
>      software included (if any);
> 4. Access, use or develop the Software in a way intended to avoid incurring fees or exceeding usage limits or quotas;
> 5. **Sell, offer to sell, distribute, disclose,**  Magento Commerce Software License Agreement v 1 3 sublicense or otherwise make
>      available the Software in a manner that is not authorized under this
>      Agreement;

For the further more details you can [read this document](https://magento.com/sites/default/files/magento-commerce-software-license-agreement.pdf) available here provided by Magento.

You can refer the **Clause 2** **`SOFTWARE LICENSE`** for the more details. & also can refer the other terms.